# How do I draw a border on a canvas in Java, by using an object from the Dimension class?

Tags: java, canvas, border, dimension

For an assignment I needed to draw a border around a 500x600 canvas on 20px from the sides, so I did it manually:

```
//upper line
myCanvas.drawLine(20, 20, 580, 20);

//bottom line
myCanvas.drawLine(20, 480, 580, 480);

//west line
myCanvas.drawLine(20, 20, 20, 480);

//east line
myCanvas.drawLine(580, 20, 580, 480);
```

But now I have to it using an object from the Dimension class, so that whenever the canvas size changes, the border changes too. So

```
myCanvas.drawLine(20, 20, (myCanvas.getHeight() - 20), 20)
```

But how do I do this? Everytime I get: cannot find symbol - method getHeight()

Comment: What type of object is `myCanvas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a number of [`Border`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/Border.html) ([How to use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)).

Something like...

```
myCanvas.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20), new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
```

Assuming that "canvas" extends from a `JComponent` of course...

Answer (score 1):

As `myCanvas` is a custom class which contains a number of swing based objects, you draw using:

```
myCanvas.drawLine(20, 20, myCanvas.getSize().height - 20, 20);
```

Comment: How do you know that `myCanvas` is of type `Graphics2D`?

Comment: Could be an Android Canvas, will need clarification from the OP.

Comment: It's in BlueJ. And myCanvas is the name of my canvas. myCanvas.drawLine(20, 20, (getHeight() - 20), 20); doesn't work either. "cannot find symbol - method getHeight()

Comment: What is the full class type name (incl package name) for `myCanvas`?

Comment: It's the Canvas class I guess. java.awt.Canvas

Comment: Don't think so. `java.awt.Canvas` doesn't have any `drawLine` method. I'm getting is a `Graphics` object. You need to get the height of your parent component but can't see what that is from the Q.

Comment: How do I find out? import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*; are the only things I'm importing. I'm sorry for my terrible Java skills, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: If your code is short you could post it. Can't do anything more without it.

Comment: Canvas is not a canvas more like a collection of random items. Anyway I've updated my answer.